# How to run 2 concurent requests with Django Test Client?

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I need to test handling of concurrent editing error on backend. 
I tried to use threads to make Client work in parallel, but I'm getting exception on test run:
"DETAIL:  There are 2 other sessions using the database."

---

Not OP's example, but I have the same problem. The expected outcome is that one of the calls is rejected due to transaction rollback.

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_transaction_failure(postdata, client):
    results_lock = threading.Lock()
    results = []

    def async_request():
       response = client.post('/edit-url', postdata)
       with results_lock:
           results.append(response)

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=async_request)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=async_request)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join(timeout=10)
    t2.join(timeout=10)

    # assertions
```

The error comes in the teardown:

```
..\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py:312: in teardown_databases
    connection.creation.destroy_test_db(old_name, verbosity, keepdb)
..\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\creation.py:263: in destroy_test_db
    self._destroy_test_db(test_database_name, verbosity)
..\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\creation.py:280: in _destroy_test_db
    % self.connection.ops.quote_name(test_database_name))
..\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py:64: in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
..\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py:94: in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
..\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py:685: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x000002606A7A0F98>
sql = 'DROP DATABASE "test_postgres"', params = None

    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql)
E               django.db.utils.OperationalError: database "test_postgres" is being accessed by other users
E               DETAIL:  There are 2 other sessions using the database.

..\..\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py:62: OperationalError
```

Comment: What kind of functionality are you going to test? Locking? Elaborate please a bit more on your goals.

Comment: I want to test that transaction locking working as needed and that two concurrent requests make only one update to DB

Comment: Could you post an example of code which fails?